# How to modify this database design to accommodate these two required requirements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-design, sql-server-2008-r2

I am a new ASP.NET developer with a good knowledge in Database Design. I am developing an intranet web-based booking system for my company and now I am struggling in designing the following required two requirements and one optional requirement:

Required Requirements:

1. The Event may have more than one time slot.
2. The user must be able to register in one of these time slot only.

Optional Requirement:

1. The user must be listed under a waiting list if there is no
   available seats in the event.

My simple database design is:

```
Users Table: UserID, Name, Department
Admins Table: UserID
Event Table: ID, Title, Description, Start_Date, End_Date, Start_Time, End_Time, Location,NumberOfSeats, isActive
BookingDetails Table: BookingID, EventID, UserID
```

**So what I should add to my database design to accommodate at least the required requirements?**

Comment: +1 on that. Increase it or youll end up getting nothing in return, maybe excessive down votes.

Comment: since it seems you are working on a booking/event management application, why don't you check out http://cqrsjourney.github.com for a fully functional reference implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. An Event may have more than 1 time slot.

Event Time Slots Table: TimeSlotID, EventID, Date, StartTime, EndTime

BookingDetails Table: BookingID, EventID, UserID, TimeSlotID

1. The User must be able to register in only one time slot per Event.

Create Unique Index on BookingDetails (EventID, UserID)